# Запуск кода powershell в программе python в контейнере docker

Tags: python, docker, powershell

На сервере linux имеется 3 контейнера docker (postgres, python app, python app), основанные на образах python:3.10.9-slim-buster, postgres:latest.
К ним необходимо добавить еще один контейнер, содержащий приложение python. Проблема в том, что это приложение использует команды powershell для получения информации из ActiveDirectory.

Функция для запуска команд powershell:

```
def execute(powershell_script):
    args = ['powershell.exe', powershell_script]
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = p.communicate()[0]
    return result
```

И в дальнейшем команда запускается:

```
command = f"$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(8192,500);" \
              f"get-aduser -filter * -properties PasswordNeverExpires " \
              f"| Where {{$_.passwordNeverExpires -eq 'true' -and $_.enabled -eq 'true'}} " \
              f"| Select-Object DistinguishedName, SamAccountName | Format-Table -AutoSize"
res = execute(command)
```

Это приложение мне нужно запустить в контейнере, но я не понимаю как это сделать.

Первый вариант - запустить контейнер на образе windows, но *объем образа очень большой* и я не уверен что можно запускать *одновременно linux и windows контейнеры*.
Второй вариант - запустить контейнер на том же образе python с установленным pwsh. Но на текущий момент мне не удается подключить модуль activedirectory:

> The term 'get-aduser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or executable program

Как этот вопрос решается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из представленной информации я предполагаю что вам нужен инструмент который позволит общаться с AD доменом. Сейчас для этого вы используете команды powershell внутри linux контейнера, что является в корне неправильным подходом. Используя python вам стоит обратить внимание на различные библиотеки для взаимодействия с AD доменом. Например, в коде вы используете команду `get-aduser`, и я нашёл на просторах интернета [такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870593/query-for-user-in-ad-using-python) которое использует библиотеку [`python-ldap`](https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/).

```
user_filter = '(sAMAccountName={})'.format(search_username)
base_dn = 'DC={},DC=com'.format(domain)
result = connection.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, user_filter)
print result
```

P.s - судя по виду кода используется python2.

В любом случае я думаю что вам придётся самостоятельно декомпозировать задачу и искать ответы на многие вопросы, пока что вопрос слишком общий.